# How to implement deep linking using branch.io in android

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am new to `branch.io` and I want to implement `deep linking` using branch.io. I want to know the basics of `branch.io` i.e. how to integrate, how it is working and other things which I need to know. I have checked many docs but I am confused so please suggest me any tutorial or doc from where I can get information step by step.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe check the documentation first? https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user didn't even read the official documentation.

Comment: i have checked the documentation but i am still confused about the working of deep linking

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput I am not sure what exactly you need help with. If you have any technical issues, I would suggest writing to `integrations@branch.io`. If you need a demo, you can get in touch with the sales team by writing in to `pg@branch.io`

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh thank you for your positive response :)